# A question about composite conditional quantum states - Westmoreland/Schumacher Book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I have a question I could not figure out in Quantum Processes, Systems and Information book of Westmoreland and Schumacher. In section 6.4 question 6.23 it is asked that,

> Show that there can be an entangled eigenstate of $Q\otimes1$ if and only if the operator $Q$ has one or more degenerate eigenvalues.

$Q$ here is an observable of Hermitian operator on system A, which is also an observable on composite system AB, so $1$ here is identity operator on system B actually. I got this but how can I prove they are entangled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is seeing that having a tensor product of two operators with degenerate eigenvalues leaves you enough room to create entanglement, working in the degenerate eigenbasis is just like working in any $d$ dimensional space and you can create entangled states, since $\mathbb{1}$ has just one maximally degenerate eigenvalue, you need $Q$ to have degenerate eigenvalues as well.

Let $|\psi_1\rangle$ and $|\psi_2\rangle$ be two orthogonal vectors that $Q|\psi_i\rangle=\alpha|\psi_i\rangle$ for $i=1,2$. Then clearly for any basis of $B$ $\{|j\rangle\}_j$, $|\psi_i\rangle\otimes |j\rangle$ are degenerate orthogonal eigenvectors of $Q\otimes \mathbb 1$ with eigenvalue $\alpha$. I claim that

$$|\phi\rangle=|\psi_1\rangle\otimes|0\rangle+|\psi_2\rangle\otimes|1\rangle $$

is an entangled eigenvector of $Q\otimes \mathbb 1$. First, it is clearly an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\alpha$. That it is entangled can be seen for example using the partial transpose criterion, but more intuitively, this is just the Bell state $|00\rangle+|11\rangle$ using $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle$ as a basis for the first Hilbert space.

Conversely, suppose $|\phi\rangle$ is an entangled eigenstate of $Q\otimes \mathbb 1$, $Q\otimes \mathbb 1|\phi\rangle=\alpha|\phi\rangle$. Let $\{|\psi\rangle_i\}_i$ be a basis of eigenvectors of $Q$ with eigenvalues $\alpha_i$. We can write $|\phi\rangle$ as

$$ |\phi\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\lambda_{ij}|\psi_i\rangle\otimes |j\rangle$$

$$\alpha\sum_{i,j}\lambda_{ij}|\psi_i\rangle\otimes |j\rangle=\alpha|\phi\rangle=Q\otimes \mathbb 1|\phi\rangle =\sum_{i,j}\lambda_{ij}\alpha_i|\psi_i\rangle\otimes |j\rangle$$

this leaves two possibilities, either $\lambda_{ij}=\lambda_j$ doesn't depend on $i$, in which case

$$ |\phi\rangle=|\psi_i\rangle \otimes \sum_j\lambda_j |j\rangle$$
or there are two eigenvectors $|\psi_i\rangle$ and $|\psi_k\rangle$ such that $\alpha_i=\alpha_k$. Since the first possibility is clearly a product state, and $|\phi\rangle$ is entangled, $Q$ must have at least one degenerate eigenvalue.